# How to disable showing home screen by swiping the locked phone

Tags: lock-screens, buttons, android-11, gestures

When my Android 11 phone is locked and dark, the Home Screen shows with some gesture. Or e.g. when putting the phone in my pants pocket, which I find annoying.

My previous phone has Android 8, which is too old to receive security upgrades, so I replaced it by a Motorola G20 phone with Android 11.

The old phone was nicely locked until you pressed the hardware power button on the side. This made it very hard to accidentally turn it back on.

The new phone turns on by the slightest handling, even without pressing any button. After a lot of experimentation I am still not sure which exact swipe or gesture turns it on

The phone has, apart from the large volume up/down button, two small buttons. The top one was assigned to Google Assistent, which I was able to disable. Now the top button brings up the home screen, the notifications, and the dots for swiping the unlock pattern.

The other small button brings up the home screen and the notifications. To get to the dots, I need to swipe up.

When the phone is locked, swiping several times diagonally brings up the home screen with notifications without dots. If the clock were an analogous clock, the swipes are roughly from 2 o'clock to 7 o'clock. I mostly need to do several swipes, sometimes 2, sometimes 4. I tried with multiple fingers, but it sometimes work with one finger, so I guess that multiple fingers is not a factor here. Anyway, I cannot conclude how many swipes are really needed. The minimum seems 3, but it can be that one swipe is enough, but that the other 2 were wrong swipes.

The fingerprint sensor feature is not set up.

My problem is e.g. that I do not know the correct android jargon which makes it hard to google this problem. This seems not to be: "anti-falsing" or "swipe unlock".

Of course, this is a new Android "feature" and should be regarded as a huge improvement of the user experience. In fact, I was stunned by the number of new features that you can turn on or off in the Settings menus. However, I like the old school principle of having explicit control, and a phone that is "off" until I explicitly press the "on" button, and not accidentally when I just grab the phone to just move it to another place on the table, or put it in or out of my pocket.

So how is this new feature called, and how to turn this off?

Comment: This looks like something that Motorola added on their own, perhaps [Moto Actions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.motorola.actions)? Otherwise, try searching "gesture" from the Settings app?

Comment: @AndrewT. Great link! This app is not available for my Moto G20, probably because those moto actions are standard built in. I searched settings for Gesture, and tried turning off Sensitive Content "Show controls when locked", in the Power Menu "Show device controls" settings. This because, from other settings descriptions, the feature I am complaning about might be called something like "show notificatins when locked". It might take a while for me to confirm if my problem is solved

Comment: @AndrewT. problem still not solved :-(

Answer (score 0):

if a password protected phone is being simply unlocked by simply swiping the home gesture, it's probably a security flaw and you're requested to contact motorola for the same.

if the device isnt set up with a secure locking mechanism, there's nothing you could do for now

Comment: The swipe does not unlock the phone, but it turns the backlight on, shows the background image of the home screen, and the notifications. To actually open the phone, you still need to enter the unlock pattern. My problem is that I don't want to have the backlight turn on with an accidental swipe, without pressing a button. The accidental swipe does not unlock the phone so it is not a security flaw.